# Hibernate Sequence constraint violation with pooled, pooled-lo optimizers on top of Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

Recently I had to partition one of the big PostgreSql table in my project and due to that, I had to change the strategy of generated values for it from IDENTITY to SEQUENCE. After that, I got a problem with sequence generation that was used by Hibernate by default. I use Hibernate **5.2.17-Final**, and by default I got: ***use_new_id_generator_mappings=true***. There is a peace of my entity object:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@ToString(of = { "id", "msisdnA", "msisdnB", "voiceChannel", "idMelody" })
/*@SequenceGenerator(name="id_generator", sequenceName="report_calls_idreportcall_seq")*/
@SQLInsert(sql = "INSERT INTO public.report_calls (dateadded, dateend, datestart, idmelody, idregion, idmelodytype, msisdn_a, msisdn_b, idvoicechannel, idreportcall) " +
           "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", check= ResultCheckStyle.NONE)
@Entity
@Table(schema = "public", name = "report_calls")
public class ReportCall {
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name="sequence_generator", strategy="enhanced-sequence",
                  parameters = {@org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "report_calls_idreportcall_seq"),
                                @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "optimizer",      value="pooled-lo"),
                                @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "initial_value",  value = "1"),
                                @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "10")})
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequence_generator")
@Column(name = "idreportcall", nullable = false)
private long          id;

@Column(name = "dateadded")
private LocalDateTime dateAdded = LocalDateTime.now();

@Column(name = "datestart")
private LocalDateTime dateStart;
...

}
```

My Hibernate configuration is:

```
@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactoryBilling() {
    log.debug("###Configuring EntityManager for billing");

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emf.setPersistenceProvider(new HibernatePersistenceProvider());
    emf.setPersistenceUnitName("billingUnit");
    emf.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());
    emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    emf.setDataSource(dataSourceBilling());
    emf.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties());
    emf.setPackagesToScan("ru.intech.rbt.common.entity.billing");


    emf.afterPropertiesSet();
    return emf.getObject();
}

private Properties jpaProperties() {
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put(DIALECT, env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    props.put(DRIVER, env.getProperty("hibernate.driver"));
    props.put(USE_NEW_ID_GENERATOR_MAPPINGS, env.getProperty("billing.hibernate.use_new_id_generator_mappings", Boolean.class));


    props.put(SHOW_SQL, env.getProperty("billing.hibernate.show_sql", Boolean.class));
    props.put(FORMAT_SQL, env.getProperty("billing.hibernate.format_sql", Boolean.class));
    props.put(USE_SQL_COMMENTS, env.getProperty("billing.hibernate.use_sql_comments", Boolean.class));

    props.put(CACHE_REGION_FACTORY, env.getProperty("billing.hibernate.cache.region.factory_class"));
    props.put(DEFAULT_CACHE_CONCURRENCY_STRATEGY, env.getProperty("billing.hibernate.cache.default_cache_concurrency_strategy"));
    props.put(USE_SECOND_LEVEL_CACHE, env.getProperty("billing.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", Boolean.class));
    props.put(USE_QUERY_CACHE, env.getProperty("billing.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", Boolean.class));
    props.put(GENERATE_STATISTICS, env.getProperty("billing.hibernate.generate_statistics", Boolean.class));

    log.info("###billingJpaProperties:" + props);

    return props;
}
```

where properties file:

```
billing.hibernate.use_new_id_generator_mappings=true
billing.hibernate.generate_statistics=false
billing.hibernate.show_sql=false
billing.hibernate.format_sql=true
billing.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true

billing.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=false
billing.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
billing.hibernate.cache.default_cache_concurrency_strategy=READ_WRITE
billing.hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
```

After changing of sequence generation strategy, I ran my application and test it with 11 calls of the save() operation of the mentioned entity via EntityManager that I got from *"billingUnit"* persistence unit. The first 10 calls were stored correctly, no problems were observed, but 11-th call failed. There are Hibernate debug traces:
1 save call()

```
2018-05-14 13:28:13,144 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl - begin
2018-05-14 13:28:13,156 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL -
    select
        nextval ('report_calls_idreportcall_seq')
2018-05-14 13:28:13,164 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG o.h.id.enhanced.SequenceStructure - Sequence value obtained: 219049790
2018-05-14 13:28:13,164 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG o.h.r.j.i.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl - HHH000387: ResultSet's statement was not registered
2018-05-14 13:28:13,164 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener - Generated identifier: 219049790, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator
2018-05-14 13:28:13,182 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl - committing
2018-05-14 13:28:13,182 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Processing flush-time cascades
2018-05-14 13:28:13,183 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Dirty checking collections
2018-05-14 13:28:13,185 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 1 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
2018-05-14 13:28:13,185 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
2018-05-14 13:28:13,187 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG o.h.internal.util.EntityPrinter - Listing entities:
2018-05-14 13:28:13,187 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG o.h.internal.util.EntityPrinter - ru.intech.rbt.common.entity.billing.ReportCall{dateStart=2018-05-14T13:28:10.591, msisdnA=992937304751, melodyType=NO_TYPE, idRegion=1, msisdnB=222, idMelody=0, id=219049790, dateEnd=2018-05-14T13:28:13.142, voiceChannel=SIP_IVR, dateAdded=2018-05-14T13:28:13.142}
2018-05-14 13:28:13,195 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL -
    INSERT
    INTO
        public.report_calls
        (dateadded, dateend, datestart, idmelody, idregion, idmelodytype, msisdn_a, msisdn_b, idvoicechannel, idreportcall)
    VALUES
        (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

2 save call()

```
2018-05-14 13:29:09,136 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl - begin
2018-05-14 13:29:09,137 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener - Generated identifier: 219049791, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator
2018-05-14 13:29:09,138 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl - committing
2018-05-14 13:29:09,138 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Processing flush-time cascades
2018-05-14 13:29:09,138 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Dirty checking collections
2018-05-14 13:29:09,138 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 1 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
2018-05-14 13:29:09,138 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
2018-05-14 13:29:09,138 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG o.h.internal.util.EntityPrinter - Listing entities:
2018-05-14 13:29:09,138 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG o.h.internal.util.EntityPrinter - ru.intech.rbt.common.entity.billing.ReportCall{dateStart=2018-05-14T13:29:06.538, msisdnA=992937304751, melodyType=NO_TYPE, idRegion=1, msisdnB=222, idMelody=0, id=219049791, dateEnd=2018-05-14T13:29:09.135, voiceChannel=SIP_IVR, dateAdded=2018-05-14T13:29:09.135}
2018-05-14 13:29:09,139 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL -
    INSERT
    INTO
        public.report_calls
        (dateadded, dateend, datestart, idmelody, idregion, idmelodytype, msisdn_a, msisdn_b, idvoicechannel, idreportcall)
    VALUES
        (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

... and so on till 11-th call where the problem occurs:

```
2018-05-14 13:35:47,871 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl - begin
2018-05-14 13:35:47,873 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL -
    select
        nextval ('report_calls_idreportcall_seq')
2018-05-14 13:35:47,875 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG o.h.id.enhanced.SequenceStructure - Sequence value obtained: 219049791
2018-05-14 13:35:47,875 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG o.h.r.j.i.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl - HHH000387: ResultSet's statement was not registered
2018-05-14 13:35:47,875 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener - Generated identifier: 219049791, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator
2018-05-14 13:35:47,876 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl - committing
2018-05-14 13:35:47,876 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Processing flush-time cascades
2018-05-14 13:35:47,876 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Dirty checking collections
2018-05-14 13:35:47,876 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 1 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
2018-05-14 13:35:47,876 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
2018-05-14 13:35:47,876 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG o.h.internal.util.EntityPrinter - Listing entities:
2018-05-14 13:35:47,877 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG o.h.internal.util.EntityPrinter - ru.intech.rbt.common.entity.billing.ReportCall{dateStart=2018-05-14T13:35:43.831, msisdnA=992937304751, melodyType=NO_TYPE, idRegion=1, msisdnB=222, idMelody=0, id=219049791, dateEnd=2018-05-14T13:35:47.870, voiceChannel=SIP_IVR, dateAdded=2018-05-14T13:35:47.870}
2018-05-14 13:35:47,877 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL -
    INSERT
    INTO
        public.report_calls
        (dateadded, dateend, datestart, idmelody, idregion, idmelodytype, msisdn_a, msisdn_b, idvoicechannel, idreportcall)
    VALUES
        (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
2018-05-14 13:35:47,891 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - could not execute statement [n/a]
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "report_calls_pkey"
  Detail: Key (idreportcall)=(219049791) already exists.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2455)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2155)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:288)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:430)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:356)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:168)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:135)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3547)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:600)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:474)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1437)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:494)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3245)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2451)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:156)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
        at ru.intech.rbt.common.dao.service.ReportService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b718a67e.save(<generated>)
        at ru.intech.rbt.common.dao.reserve.proxy.ReportServiceProxy.save(ReportServiceProxy.java:88)
        at ru.intech.rbt.common.context.SubscriberContext.createReport(SubscriberContext.java:568)
        at ru.intech.ivr.box.threads.CallProcessor.processCDR(CallProcessor.java:466)
        at ru.intech.ivr.box.threads.IvrProcessor.run(IvrProcessor.java:184)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2018-05-14 13:35:47,892 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23505
2018-05-14 13:35:47,892 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "report_calls_pkey"
  Detail: Key (idreportcall)=(219049791) already exists.
2018-05-14 13:35:47,898 [992937304751>222[IVR] IVR] DEBUG o.h.r.t.b.j.i.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl - JDBC transaction marked for rollback-only (exception provided for stack trace)
java.lang.Exception: exception just for purpose of providing stack trace
```

Can anybody explain me such strange behavior of Hibernate framework, please? I don't understand why does it generate the same id that Postgres method *nextval()* using my ***report_calls_idreportcall_seq***? By the way, the sequence initially  (before test) looked like that:

- current value: 219049790
- increment: 1
- minimum: 1
- maximum: 9223372036854775807
- cache:   1
- cycled: NO

If I set increment_size = 1 as a parameter of @GenericGenerator everything becomes fine, but I don't want to do that and since it will reduce performance due to the fact that hibernate will hit the database each time when it needs to store new report_call and in production environment I have about 300 threads that in concurrent mode saves these items all the time. Is there any chance to avoid setting increment_size=1 or optimizer="hi/lo" (as I see it is also hit the database to get new id by nextval() each time) ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I understood the root cause of my problem. I forced Hibernate to use increment_size=10 and at the same time configured my Postgres sequence to increment new primary key id with value 1 and Postgres was discouraged when Hibernate tried to save an item with id value when 10 values bigger than id had already been stored.

In such a way there was nothing special in that Hibernate took exactly the value that db sequence provide it with since it expected that db also configured to increment pk value to the same gap=>10. When I changed "increment" of my ***report_calls_idreportcall_seq*** everything become fine and Hibernate doesn't generate exceptions anymore and at the same time, it hit the db with nextval() request once per 10 save() calls.